# How do you write a division of a division when it can't be simplified?

Tags: notation

I have an equation that cannot be simplified, but looks ugly written out.

$N^y_j = \alpha_{y_j} + \Bigl\lfloor\frac{P^y_i}{\Bigl\lfloor{\frac{P^y_i}{N^y_j}\Bigr\rfloor}}\Bigr\rfloor$

I thought to use a one-line divide in the divisor which looks nicer aesthetically, but I'm not convinced:

$N^y_j = \alpha_{y_j} + \Bigl\lfloor\frac{P^y_i}{\lfloor{P^y_i \div N^y_j\rfloor}}\Bigr\rfloor$

What is the recommended way to write such an equation, please? Or can the equation be restructured somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ and $N$ are natural number sequences, then you can use this instead:

$$N^y_j=\alpha_{y_j}+\Bigl\lfloor\frac{P^y_iN^y_j}{P^y_i-P^y_i\bmod{N^y_j}}\Bigr\rfloor$$